# Why does store bought Starbucks ground coffee prepared at home taste and look different from the real version?

Tags: flavor, ground-coffee, iced-coffee

I recently started trying to make my own coffee instead of just buying them in bottles or somewhere else, and I found ground pumpkin spice at Walmart. I decided to try it, but since I don’t really know what I’m doing, it is coming out absolutely not right. I can still taste remnants of the real version when I drink it, but my version is transparent and tastes a lot less creamy VS the real version which is opaque and a very much lighter color. What’s the best way to try and make it taste more like the real deal? I’m sure adding milk is a part of it, but I’m not sure how/where/when to add it or if I just need creamer or something. Also, I’m trying to make it iced and I just use a basic gourmia GCM3260. Any help would be appreciated because I’m struggling to find information :(

To be more clear, [this is the exact coffee maker I'm using](https://www.gourmia.com/item.asp?item=10354) and [this is the coffee grounds I'm using.](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Starbucks-Pumpkin-Spice-Ground-Flavored-Coffee-100-Arabica-Naturally-Flavored-17-oz/566582409?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&wl13=220&adid=22222222277566582409_117755028669_12420145346&wmlspartner=wmtlabs&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=501107745824&wl4=pla-294505072980&wl5=9027209&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=local&wl12=566582409&wl13=220&veh=sem_LIA&gclid=CjwKCAjwtKmaBhBMEiwAyINuwA8tH_k27rQ_NXn-FR1ey-1mx7sxcDWAEykS3KGVNitIyMMCutLbUxoC0jQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) The coffee and the coffee maker have 2 different directions, so I've tried following them both, but they both don't seem to come out too correctly. I'm trying to make it iced, as the machine has iced as an option (although it still brews with hot water so I don't think it would interfere that much with how it comes out). Also, I'm not sure what brew method it's sold for as asked by fixer, because the only directions the coffee actually has is just 1) use 1 and a half tablespoons of coffee and 2) add 6 fluid ounces of cold filtered water. But the only videos I've seen of people making this use hot water?? As a side note, I just went ahead and tried making it the hot option instead of the iced option on the maker, and it came out darker, but it still tasted super bitter, although I'm not sure whether to follow the coffee machine's instructions or whats on the bag with the coffee.

Quick edit - Right after I made the hot coffee I tried icing it and adding creamer. It looked a whole lot more like the real starbucks version, but it didn't really taste like too much. I didn't add all that much creamer, only 5 teaspoons for a relatively big(ish) glass.

Comment: Welcome! In order to understand what went wrong, we need a clearer description of what exactly you did so far - and ideally also what you want to achieve. Please [edit] your post and we’ll be happy to help you figure out how to get your desired cup. The [tour] and the [help], especially [ask] will explain more.

Comment: I am also confused about your setup. Are you using instant coffee with a classic (pour-over) machine? You mention pumpkin spice?

Comment: Looks like an interesting question, but let me add to what Stephie asked for clarification on. By "store bought", you're referring to the Starbucks-branded products sold at grocery stores, rather than what they sell at their own Starbucks shops? They sell ground coffee. What I'm familiar with is a medium grind for use in a drip coffee maker. I'm not familiar with micro ground (sounds like a grind for espresso machines, which isn't typically ground and packaged in advance, other than maybe for pods). Can you clarify what that is, and what brew method it's sold for? (cont'd)

Comment: Does the coffee come with any kind of preparation instructions on the package, or have you checked the Starbucks web site to see if they have instructions there (instructions specific to their product are likely to give better results than generic instructions)? And by "bottles", you're referring to ready-to-drink coffee beverages?

Comment: @fixer1234 there is an instant coffee line from Starbucks featuring “micro” ground beans. I have a hunch that this may be what we’re dealing with here.

Comment: @fixer1234 I added some more information in the post that would answer some of your (and other's) questions, but yeah I'm referring to the ones at grocery stores like you said. And by bottles, I do mean the ones that are just already ready to go when you open them. Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: Ah. So you have a drip / filter machine and coffee for that. Small clarification: the “cold water” in the instructions refers to what goes into the coffee maker, not what goes on the grounds, that’ll be always hot in this case. You should always start with cold water as it’s “fresher” (and I’m sure someone can elaborate on that if needed).

Comment: I thought about how to answer this question, and a good answer would be **really** long. Partly because it's a big subject if you want to understand the "why", rather than just getting a coffee recipe, and partly because it actually consists of several different questions. This would be a lot easier for people to answer if you could break it up into several focused questions.  For example: What are the basics of brewing good-tasting hot coffee in my coffee maker? What are the basics of making good ice coffee with my coffee maker? (cont'd)

Comment: What's the proper way to make these specialty coffees that use milk? Why do these various coffee beverages made at home taste different from what is served in a Starbucks shop? I think you'll get more, better, and faster answers if you can repost this along those lines. I started jotting down some thoughts, and I was soon on my way to writing a book.  :-)